# Passing values from form to form? and refresh From?

Tags: c#, forms

I need help using the changing the seatarray in C#.

I have a listbox with the seatarrays on it. I think the value has change, but I don't see it maybe because my listbox is not refresh?

Anyway to relaunch form 1?

Form 1

```
  private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//A
            {

                using (Form2 f = new Form2())
                {
                    f.SomeValue = 'T';
                    f.ShowDialog();
                    test2 = f.SomeValue;//test2 is char type variable
                    seatArray[num - 1].A = test2;//seat array A is a char type


                }
            }
```

Form 2

```
public char SomeValue { get; set; }
        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SomeValue = 'V';
           // this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What is the definition of  Test2, is SomeValue a method or a control. You need to be explicit on exactly what you are trying to do. You have not given us near enough information to answer your question.

Comment: test2 is a char, cause the contents of A  in seat array are char type.

Comment: You need to remove and reassign your seatArray to your listbox's DataSource in order for your change to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to flesh out my comment a bit. When you ask a question you should try to make the code that you give self explanatory and able to be executed to verify your problem. I had to make some assumptions but this code here I think will show you what I am meaning by my comment.

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static Seats[] seatArray = new Seats[15];
    char test2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < seatArray.Length-1; i++)
        {
            Seats tmp = new Seats();
            tmp.A = (char)(65+i);
            seatArray[i] = tmp;
        }

        listBox1.DataSource = seatArray;
    }

    private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Form2 f = new Form2())
        {
            f.SomeValue = 'T';
            f.ShowDialog();
            test2 = f.SomeValue;//test2 is char type variable
            seatArray[2].A = test2;//seat array A is a char type
            listBox1.DataSource = null; //remove array from the listbox's datasource
            listBox1.DataSource = seatArray; //reassign it to it.
        }

    }   

}

public class Seats
{
    public char A { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return A.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: seat array is static its Seats[] seatArray = new Seats[15];

And A in seatarray its a Char Type.

Comment: That is what I was talking about, without your implementation we have to construct our own ideas of what your code looks like. Though what I am saying on removing/re-adding your DataSource still applies

Comment: can you edit the code for an static one? idk if

listBox1.DataSource = null; //remove your seatArray from your listbox's DataSource
            listBox1.DataSource = seatarray; //Reassign it

Comment: @user3663038 I have changed it to use a static.